# How do you edit the HTML for MediaWiki's Special:UserLogin page in MW 1.28?

Tags: php, mediawiki

Previously, there was a class called UserloginTemplate extending BaseTemplate that you were free to copypaste into your own file and use instead in the class loader.

Now, I cannot even find what file this HTML is coming from. I have found `includes/specialpage/LoginSignupSpecialPage.php` ... but it's Abstract.

```
abstract class LoginSignupSpecialPage extends AuthManagerSpecialPage {
```

I have no idea where to begin and any information I can find about this is for older versions of MediaWiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is a little different than before but not too hard.

1. Create a class for extending the class `includes/specials/SpecialUserLogin.php` in your extension's directory. I named mine `XenForoAuthSpecialUserLogin.php`.
2. In your new class file, extend `SpecialUserLogin` as you typically would.

   `class XenForoAuthSpecialUserLogin extends SpecialUserLogin`

   Then, overload the method `protected function getPageHtml($formHtml)` and return the modified HTML you want.
3. In your extension's `extension.js`, add an `AutoloadClasses` entry for your new class.
4. In your `LocalSettings.php`, add this line to replace the special page with your new class.

   `$wgSpecialPages['Userlogin'] = [XenForoAuthSpecialUserLogin::class];`

   Beware! Although all references use `UserLogin`, this key (and the page URL) is `Userlogin` with a lowercase L.
5. You should now see your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`AuthChangeFormFields`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/AuthChangeFormFields) hook. See the documentation of [`HTMLForm`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/HTMLForm) on what kind of changes you can do. Note that for any change to what kind of data can be submitted (e.g. a new form field), you need to write a [provider](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SessionManager_and_AuthManager#As_a_provider), but if you just want to add extra text or such, you can add [`info`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/HTMLForm/tutorial3#info) fields via the hook.